# user_groups permission for facebook

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-group

I have one problem in facebook permission for auth. My application need user_groups permission. And I make this in settings for my app, but in dialog exist only standart permission "your basic info". In settings for my app, in tab permission, I click "preview login dialog"-> and in this preview my permissions exist! Where my mistake?

Comment: do you use `Javascript API` ? please show the code how you `FB.login()`.

Comment: no i use PHP! https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/fb.php&code=$code! and access_token return without needed permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Facebook PHP SDK, please update your code when getting login url:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_groups'));
```

Comment: No i not using PHP SDK!

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/fb.php&code=$code!

and request json object

Comment: $url = https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/fb.php&code=$code!

$response = file_get_contents($url);
parse_str($response);

and variable $access_token content access_token

Comment: But login dialog is not correct

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=235128583256760&redirect_uri=http://empnet.ru/fb.php&response_type=code check this! in dialg noe exist group permission

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: I dont like SDK! but write this, i answer for my quations!!! I forget "scope" attribute in dialog query string 

Right query look like this https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&scope=user_groups&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/fb.php&response_type=code